# Jquery hover over anchor nested inside a div and .mouseleave fires. Why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/gC353/2/

So the .mouseenter fires when you hover over .dd-item. And .dropdown fades in. Great.

But when you hover over the a which is nested inside .dd-item. .mouseleave seems to fire.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
$('.dd-item').mouseenter(function(){
$('.dropdown',this).fadeIn(100);
});

$('.dd-item').mouseout(function(){
$('.dropdown').fadeOut(100);
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: That's interesting how you've mentioned the correct answer in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mouseleave()` won't be triggered if the cursor leaves that element for a child element; `mouseout()` will:

```
$('.dd-item').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.dropdown',this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gC353/3/)